# how to push multiple objects into one object serially

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have 2 or multiple objects in a single variable and i want to push these objects into one object.

```
let a = {"device_type":"iphone","filter_data":{"title":{"value":"Lorem Ipsum..","data":{}},"message":{"value":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing...","data":{}},"dismiss_button":{"value":"Ok","data":{}},"action_url":{"value":"","data":{"type":"custom"}}}}

{"device_type":"iphone","filter_data":{"message":{"value":"Push Message goes here.","data":{}}}}
```

I want the output to be:

```
{
  "0": {
    "device_type": "iphone",
    "filter_data": {
      "title": {
        "value": "Lorem Ipsum..",
        "data": {}
      },
      "message": {
        "value": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing...",
        "data": {}
      },
      "dismiss_button": {
        "value": "Ok",
        "data": {}
      },
      "action_url": {
        "value": "",
        "data": {
          "type": "custom"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "1": {
    "device_type": "iphone",
    "filter_data": {
      "message": {
        "value": "Push Message goes here.",
        "data": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: which data is a string two object in a single string or separate? paste the data how they actually are.

Comment: like I've one variable in which this two object comes one by one

Comment: what do you mean one by one? still your question is not clear.

Comment: var a = {obj_1}{obj_2}.....{obj_n} like this

Comment: are all objects starts with `device_type` in the string?

Comment: yes exactly all starting with the device_type

Comment: so variable `a` is a string or what datatype?

Comment: a is a string and that contains all the objects like {obj_1}{obj_2}.....{obj_n}

Comment: posted the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace `}{` with a `},{`, parse it and take [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for getting an object with indices as properties from an array.

```js
const
    data = '{"device_type":"iphone","filter_data":{"title":{"value":"Lorem Ipsum..","data":{}},"message":{"value":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing...","data":{}},"dismiss_button":{"value":"Ok","data":{}},"action_url":{"value":"","data":{"type":"custom"}}}}{"device_type":"iphone","filter_data":{"message":{"value":"Push Message goes here.","data":{}}}}';
    result = Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(`[${data.replace(/\}\{/g, '},{')}]`));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: I'm getting output like:
{ '0':
   '{"device_type":"iphone","filter_data":{"title":{"value":"Lorem Ipsum..","data":{}},"message":{"value":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing...","data":{}},"dismiss_button":{"value":"Ok","data":{}},"action_url":{"value":"","data":{"type":"custom"}}}}' }
{ '0':
   '{"device_type":"iphone","filter_data":{"message":{"value":"Push Message goes here.","data":{}}}}' }

Comment: please add the string, you ha exactly to the question. which characters do you have between the two objects look alikes?

Comment: don't have anything between two objects. I've string like

let a = {obj_1}{obj_2}.....{obj_n}

Comment: This `let a = {obj_1}{obj_2}.....{obj_n}` is not a string  definition , this is how you initialise string `let a = "{obj_1}{obj_2}.....{obj_n}"`. Please confirm this is what you have. Also either update the question or u can accept @NinaScholz 's  answer

Comment: that is not possible, without having a string.

Comment: @KunalDholiya Then what you have is a syntax error. Could post snippet of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

If they're in an array, it's fairly simple - just use `reduce`:

```js
const data = [{"device_type":"iphone","filter_data":{"title":{"value":"Lorem Ipsum..","data":{}},"message":{"value":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing...","data":{}},"dismiss_button":{"value":"Ok","data":{}},"action_url":{"value":"","data":{"type":"custom"}}}},{"device_type":"iphone","filter_data":{"message":{"value":"Push Message goes here.","data":{}}}}];
const res = data.reduce((a, c, i) => (a[i] = c, a), {});
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.protoype.match` to separate each object then `Array.protoype.reduce` to get expected oject.

```js
let a = '{"device_type":"iphone","filter_data":{"title":{"value":"Lorem Ipsum..","data":{}},"message":{"value":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing...","data":{}},"dismiss_button":{"value":"Ok","data":{}},"action_url":{"value":"","data":{"type":"custom"}}}}{"device_type":"iphone","filter_data":{"message":{"value":"Push Message goes here.","data":{}}}}';
let objects = a.match(/({"device_type".*?}}}})/g).map(e => JSON.parse(e));
console.log('Array of objects',objects)
const out = {...[objects]};
console.log('\ndesired output',out)
```

Also, it seems to be useless to convert the array into an object when the keys are just the indexes.

Comment: this is giving output like {obj1} {"0":{obj1}} {obj2} {"0":{obj2}}

Comment: If we could push this all in one array with comma separate then also i can use it!